# Backup VM RBAC assignments

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

Restoring a VM that has been deleted, correctly restores the VM. Is there any way of backing up the associated VM RBAC role assignments so that we dont have to manually recreate them after restoration ?

Comment: check this it might helps you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-rbac-rs-vault

Comment: This tells me which RBAC controls Azure Backup, but not how to backup role assignments.